# Please correct the R code for steepest ascent

Tags: r

I have written the following code in R for steepest ascent

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
y <- c(1.3,1.9,2.4,2.5,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7,2.7,2.7)
del <-0.01
tol <- 0.00001
b1 <- 2
b2 <- 2.5
sum1 = 0
sum2 = 0
sum3 = 0
sum4 = 0
accept= FALSE 
post <- function(b1,b2){
  for (i in 1:10) {
  sum1 = sum1 + (y[i]*exp(1-exp(-x[i]/b2)))
  sum2 = sum2 + exp(2-2*exp(-x[i]/b2))
  sum3 = sum3 + y[i]*x[i]*exp(1-(x[i]/b2))-exp(-x[i]/b2)
  sum4 = sum4 + x[i]*exp(2-(x[i]/b2)-2*exp(-x[i]/b2))
  }
  f = function(b1,b2){ 
    (-0.01*(b1+b2))+(100*b1*sum1)-(50* sum2*(b1)^2) 
  }
  db1 = function(b1,b2){
    -0.01+(100*sum1)-(100*b1*sum2)
  }
  db2 = function(b1,b2){ 
    -0.01+(100*(b1/b2)^2*sum4)-(100*(b1/(b2)^2)*sum3)
  }

  while (accept==FALSE){
    b1_new = del*db1(b1,b2) + b1
    b2_new = del*db2(b1,b2) + b2
    db1_new = db1(b1_new,b2_new)
    db2_new = db2(b1_new,b2_new)
  }
  if(abs(db1_new) > abs(db1(b1,b2)) & abs(db2_new) < abs(db2(b1,b2))){
    accept=TRUE
    del = del/2
    db1_new = db1(b1_new,b2_new)
    db2_new = db2(b1_new,b2_new)
    new_point = c(db1(b1_new,b2_new),db2(b1_new,b2_new))
  }
}  
print(c(b1,b2))
```

This code does not update my values and am unsure what is wrong with the code. Any help is appreciated

I have tried changing this code many times however always seem to get an error or the values do not update. Am expecting the new values to be printed after the code

Comment: @zephryl: it most certainly does return the value of the variable `new_point`, as this is the value of the last expression in the function body.

Comment: The new_point assignment is within an 'if' statement, so if the 'if' statement condition is not met, the function will not return new_point. Try to explicitly return new_point.

Comment: @FabioCorrea: that is correct. The return statement should be explicit. I was merely disagreeing with the point that the function doesn't return anything, because unfortunately for many new R users it always does (even `(function() {})()` returns `NULL`).

Comment: 'Please correct my code' is not a question and you haven't even asked a question anywhere. SO is not a personal code writing service when you can't be bothered to explain your question.

Comment: @user438383: I am not a native speaker, but the question was pretty clear to me, although implicit: why does the code not modify the values b1 and b2?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't call your function at all nowhere in your code. You probably want to call `new_point <- post(b1, b2)`.

Secondly, your function takes the parameters `b1` and `b2`, but when you use the variables in your code, they are local. That means that changing b1 and b2 within the function does not change the global variables.

```
b <- 10
modb <- function(b) {
 b <- 20
}
modb()
print(b)
```

...will print `10`.

Thirdly: you are calculating variables called `db1_new` and `db2_new` in your code, but you are not returning them. That does not mean that the code does not return *anything* at all, it does: it returns the value of the last expression evaluated (which is probably `new_point`), but that is probably not what you would like to have. You should specify the return value explicitely, e.g. with `return(c(db1_new, db2_new))`.

Fourth, the statement `while(accept == FALSE) { ... }` will never finish, because you do not change the value of `accept` in your loop. Hope that helps.